# Newtonsoft.Json Проблема сериализации

Tags: c#, json, api

Делал запрос к своему Api используя restsharp.
При запросе добавлял Header с json-строчкой. Сериализовал так:

```
string content = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<Song>(item);
```

Всё прекрасно работало, но я решил попробовать Newtonsoft.JSON.
Сериализовал так:

```
string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
```

И после этого начал ловить исключение: "Specified value has invalid Control characters. (Parameter 'value')"

В item есть свойства с кириллицей.

Может кто сталкивался с этим?

Comment: начал ловить исключения в какой момент? Если в момент сериализации, приведи пример объекта, который в одном случае нормально сериализуется, а в другом нет. Если в момент десериализации - пример входного Json

Comment: Люди переходят с `Newtonsoft.Json` на `System.Text.Json` как на новый, более быстрый и не менее надежный сериализатор, а вы наоборот. Почему?

Comment: Спортивный интерес. Просто решил попробовать.

Comment: Возможно, это поможет: https://qna.habr.com/q/215447